# Q: Reset to last applied values button in obiee 12c not working properly?

Tags: obiee

I am working on OBIEE 12c version where I have created a dashboard having multiple filters in the analysis with apply and reset button. While 'signing out' and 'signing in' again with same user I tried to click on "Reset to last applied values" button for selecting last applied filters before this session. The button is not working. What could I do to resolve this type of issue?

Comment: You start with a precise version. There were about 40 "12c" versions. Please be precise. "12.2.1.4.201020" is precise. "12c" or "12.2.1.3" are not precise.

Comment: Precise version of obiee is "12.2.1.2.0" .

Comment: Really? An unpatched 12.2.1.2.0 from October 2016 and you never ever installed a single bundle patch? So a totally outdated, no longer supported version which wasn't even lifted above its dot zero level? Ask your admin because no company should run something unsupported like that. It's just not serious or professional.